# Logic to convert string of words to number

Tags: hash, hive, teradata

I am looking for a logic which will help me in coverting a string to number in teradata and hive.

It should be easily implementable in Tearadata as I dont have permission to deploy a UDF in TD. In hive if it is not simple I can easily write a UDF.

My requirement -  Lets say I have columns sender_country, receiver country. I want to generate a number for concat('sender_country','_','receiver_country')
The number should always be same if the countries appear again.

Below is the illustration

```
UID sender_country  receiver_country    concat  number
1   US              UK                  US_UK   198760
2   FR              IN                  FR_IN   146785
3   CH              RU                  CH_RU   467892  
4   US              UK                  US_UK   198760
```

It should be in a way where all unique combinations of a country should have unique values. Like in above example `US_US` is repeated, it has same corresponding `number`.

I tried `hashbucket(hashrow('concat'))` in TD, but don't know its equivalent implementation in hive.

Similarly we have `hash()` function in hive, but don't have its equivalent function in TD.

I could not find any hash functions which returns similar values in TD and Hive too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply convert each character into a number:

```
Ascii(Substr(sender_country,1,1))*1000000+
Ascii(Substr(sender_country,2,1))*10000+
Ascii(Substr(receiver_country,1,1))*100+
Ascii(Substr(receiver_country,2,1))
```

returns `85838575` for `US,UK`

Comment: But the size of `country code` is not fixed. For example there could be a value like `'IND'` for `country` column at times

Comment: @RahulSinghvi: Most companies either use the standardized codes, either 2 or 3 letter ISO (or even 3 digit ISO without need for conversion, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code). When you mix you will run into problems, this should be fixed during load. There's MD5 & BLAKE2 UDFs available for Teradata, you might talk to your DBA

Comment: Thankyou so much @dnoeth